# Circular dependency in constructor initialization list

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, circular-dependency, initialization-list

Is the following well-defined?

```
class A;
class B;

// define A, which takes B& in constructor
// define B, which takes A& in constructor

class C
{
    A a;
    B b;
public:
    C() : a(b), b(a) { /* stuff with a and b */ }
}
```

Full example at [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/EuVNca).

Is it safe/well-defined so long as the constructors for `A` and `B` don't do anything with the references they get?

Comment: Why the downvote? Let me know how I can improve the question.

Comment: I don't think compiler allows you to do `a(b)` because when `a` is being initialized, `b` is not initialized yet.

Comment: @user3528438: It sure does, the ideone example compiles and runs. But is it because I am lucky or because it is well-defined in the standard?

Comment: Interesting, it seems like the object is "allocated but not initialized". https://ideone.com/V5uPyr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

N4140 [class.cdtor]/1 reads:

> For an object with a non-trivial constructor, referring to any non-static member or base class of the object
>   before the constructor begins execution results in undefined behavior. For an object with a non-trivial
>   destructor, referring to any non-static member or base class of the object after the destructor finishes
>   execution results in undefined behavior.

While this passage itself doesn't imply that the behavior is otherwise well-defined, the following example shows that it is. Here is an excerpt:

```
struct B : public A { int j; Y y; }; // non-trivial
extern B bobj;
B* pb = &bobj; // OK
```

So the answer is: yes, the behavior in your case is well defined if you aren't referring to members or base classes of `b` in the constructor of `A`.

Comment: That's intuitive enough. So then [user3528438's example](https://ideone.com/V5uPyr) is undefined behavior because `m_a.m_value` is accessed before `m_a`'s constructor runs. Thanks for digging up the reference!

Comment: @Claudiu Right, it's definitely UB.

Comment: Can you bind a *reference* to an object that has not yet been constructed? There are differences between the semantics of pointers and references. For example, `int* p = nullptr; int& r = *p;` is considered UB, but `int* r = &*p;` is arguably not UB (C explicitly allows it, for example).

Comment: @dyp Unfortunately I couldn't find an explicit quote about references, only that [class.cdtor]/3 may imply that if we have something to convert from, it was obtained with well-defined means.