# Binding reference to an object before construction

Tags: c++, reference, language-lawyer, c++14

Is the behavior of the following code well-defined?

```
struct X { int i; }; // trivial
struct Y : X { Y(){} }; // non-trivial

extern X xobj;
int& r1 = xobj.i; // #1
X xobj;

extern Y yobj;
Y& r2 = yobj;     // #2
// int& r3 = yobj.i; // #3 - this is UB according to the standard
Y yobj;
```

This code is inspired by the example in the C++ standard, namely draft N4140 [class.cdtor]/1.

That's what that paragraph reads:

> For an object with a non-trivial constructor, referring to any non-static member or base class of the object
>   before the constructor begins execution results in undefined behavior. For an object with a non-trivial
>   destructor, referring to any non-static member or base class of the object after the destructor finishes
>   execution results in undefined behavior.

An example follows, which shows how *pointers* may and may not be bound to objects.

So intuitively it seems that `#1` and `#2` are well-defined, while `#3` invokes UB if uncommented, but, first, examples are not normative, second, there's no mention of references in the example, and third and the most important, the above paragraph doesn't imply that otherwise the behavior is well-defined. Or does it? Or maybe there's another relevant quote in the standard that I missed?

**Edit**: The answer may (arguably) be yes if the objects have static storage duration, but they can be also local, e.g:

```
struct A { A(){} };
struct B { B(A&){} };

struct C {
    B b;
    A a;
    C() : b(a) {}
};

int main() {
    C c;
}
```

Actually this was the initial inspiration for this question, see [Circular dependency in constructor initialization list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29809241/circular-dependency-in-constructor-initialization-list)

Comment: "referring to any non-static member [...] results in undefined behavior" -  referring is exactly what a reference does (hence the name).

Comment: @molbdnilo I understand that, but it doesn't explain what happens *otherwise* (e.g referring to ... before the constructor begins for class with trivial constructor), that's the point of the question.

Comment: "referring to it" means mentioning it (it's the english word "refer") .

Comment: Relevant: [CWG issue 1530](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#1530) and [basic.life]/6

Comment: @AntonSavin Unless I misunderstand English, it's implied by the special case "For an object with a non-trivial constructor, [...]" that the behaviour is well-defined in other cases.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior of #2 is definitely well-defined. As mentioned by @dyp, the relevant paragraph is in [basic.life]:

[image]

Binding the glvalue `yobj` to a reference is fine, since its storage lasts throughout the duration of the program ([basic.stc.static]/1) and the reference is bound to a valid object - aliveness aside - which meets the requirement in ([dcl.ref]/5). Similarly, for the second example you showed, as long as no operation is performed on members of the `A` subobject, the above paragraph applies as well since the constructor of `C` is called on the allocated storage `this` refers to.

Answer (score 0):

> [...] there's no mention of references in the example [...]

You mean, except for

> [...] **referring** to any non-static member [...]

From the passage you quote, I would say this line causes undefined behaviour:

```
int& r3 = yobj.i; // #3
```

because you are:

> [...] referring to any non-static member or base class of the object before the constructor begins execution[.]

Also, for this:

> and the most important, the above paragraph doesn't imply that otherwise the behavior is well-defined.

You're right, it doesn't:

> Undefined behavior may be expected when this International Standard **omits any explicit definition of behavior** or when a program uses an erroneous construct or erroneous data.

Comment: #3 invokes UB, there's no question about that. But  #2 is (intuitively) equivalent to `Y* p2 = &yobj` which is clearly marked as well-defined in the standard example (but not in the normative text)

Comment: Is it? What does "base class" mean then, if not `yobj`?

Comment: It is possible that referring to non-static data members and base classes is UB because of virtual base classes. The vtable is set up during construction, so you cannot access neither members of nor virtual base classes themselves before the construction has started.

Comment: If "base class" means "the object itself" (`== yobj`), then referencing `yobj` itself produces UB. It's not entirely clear to me what exactly the "base class" is, especially since it doesn't mention "members of the base class", but the base class itself.

Comment: As far as I know, *base class* never refers to the type itself. It should probably be *base class subobject* here, though.

Comment: @AntonSavin the standard does not state that references are just pointers. Intuition about pointers being applied to references (where you pretend the reference is just an immutable pointer with auto-dereferencing) should be used very cautiously; it often works, but never trust it.

Comment: @Yakk true, and I understand that, that's why I'm asking.